# Read csv file and output into a list box & list that can be edited

Tags: c#, list, csv, class, inventory

I'm trying to make a Windows Forms App that allows the user to load a chosen csv file (any csv file that has the same format) and be able to edit the list. The csv file has to be opened using OpenFileDialog and [output into a list box in a formatted way](http://prntscr.com/j3k166). Once the user has loaded the csv file, the option to change the data of the list needs to be added.

Form code:

```
    public partial class inventoryForm : Form
    {
    OpenFileDialog ipFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    public inventoryForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void loadInvDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inventoryListBox.Items.Clear(); //clear listbox items
        if (ipFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //show dialog box
        {
            Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
            var inventories = inventory.Load(ipFile.FileName);
            //sets the datasource of the list box to the collection of inventory
            //by default it calls the ToString() method which which overrode
            //to provide columar output
            inventoryListBox.DataSource = inventories;
        }
    }
```

---

Class code:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int StartingQty { get; set; }
    public int QtyMinRestck { get; set; }
    public int QtySold { get; set; }
    public int QtyRStcked { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public Inventory()
    {

    }

    //this overrides the default .ToString() method to provide
    //columnar output and formats the UnitPrice to currrency
    //this requires the following: using System.Globalization;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}"
            , Id.PadRight(20, ' ')
            , ItemName.PadRight(20, ' ')
            , StartingQty.ToString().PadLeft(20, ' ')
            , QtyMinRestck.ToString().PadLeft(20, ' ')
            , QtySold.ToString().PadLeft(20, ' ')
            , QtyRStcked.ToString().PadLeft(20, ' ')
            , UnitPrice.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).PadLeft(20, ' '));
    }

    //this loads a collection of inventory objects from a file
    //it would ignore any lines with errors
    public IEnumerable<Inventory> Load(string InventoryFileName)
    {
        var inventories = new List<Inventory>();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(InventoryFileName))
        {
            sr.ReadLine(); //skip the first line
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    var fields = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

                    inventories.Add(new Inventory
                    {
                        Id = fields[0]
                        ,
                        ItemName = fields[1]
                        ,
                        StartingQty = Int32.Parse(fields[2])
                        ,
                        QtyMinRestck = Int32.Parse(fields[3])
                        ,
                        QtySold = Int32.Parse(fields[4])
                        ,
                        QtyRStcked = Int32.Parse(fields[5])
                        ,
                        UnitPrice = Decimal.Parse(fields[6])
                    });
                }
                catch
                {
                    //handle error here
                }
            }
        }
        return inventories;
    }
}
```

I was told that this code I have needs to be serialized because it's currently deserialized. I'm not sure how to do this. I believe my current code does not allow the user to edit even if the code was added.

Answer (score 0):

A `ListBox` can **display** your class but is ill-suited for all your other tasks.

Instead go for a `DataGridView`!

- First look up how to *'read cvs to DataTable'* and do it.
- Next how to *'bind DataTable to DataGridView'*.
- Finally how to *'serialize a DataTable'*.

While the display in a `ListBox` may be ok, as long as you restrict it to fixed font, you can't edit it.

Your class has only simple data types and can be made serializable by simply attatching the `[Serializable]` attribute. This would apply to a `List<Inventory>` as well but there is a better way.

`DataTable` is serializable out of the box and a DGV lets you edit all cells by default..

The resulting code will consist of one method to load cvs to xml (`GetDataTableFromCsv`) and one or two lines each to save and load the data to xml (Serialization). All are to be found in the first one or two google hits.

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here
            head = reader.ReadLine(); 

            while(!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split(';'); 

                Class rep;

                if (line[2] == "2.0")
                    rep = new Class2(line);
                 else if (line[2] == "2.1")
                    rep = new Class21(line);
                else
                    rep = new Class51(line); 

                listReproduktoru.Add(rep); 
            }
        }
        UpdateView();
enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please do note that your answer could be improved with a description of how it solves the problem, give some context. BTW, I find your code incomplete (no definition of Class, Class2, Class21, Class51) and im not sure it addresses the problem of the question.